# Ordering the DriveItems from the Graph API only possible on name property

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

The `DriveItem`s received from the Microsoft Graph API must be ordered on customer needs, but the only property where ordering is possible is `name` *(for so far I've found it)*.

I've tried many properties listed below. The URL + path of the queries below is `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/root/Children` for each.

| Query | Working |
| --- | --- |
| `?$orderby=name asc` | Yes |
| `?$orderby=createdDateTime asc` | No → Operation not supported |
| `?$orderby=lastModifiedDateTime asc` | No → The property Modified is not supported for OrderBy. |
| `?$orderby=size asc` | No → The property SMTotalFileStreamSize is not supported for OrderBy. |
| `?$orderby=createdBy/user/displayname asc` | No → Operation not supported |
| `?$orderby=createdby/user/email asc` | No → OrderBy not supported. |
| `?$orderby=lastModifiedBy/user/displayname asc` | No → Operation not supported |
| `?$orderby=lastModifiedBy/user/email asc` | No → OrderBy not supported. |

According to the documentation I read, it should be working.

> This method supports the `$expand`, `$select`, `$skipToken`, `$top` and `$orderby` [OData query parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters) to customize the response.
>
> Source: [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Why is `name` the only property to order the results and could the others be possible by a setting?

Comment: We opened an issue at Microsoft. If you want you can upvote our feature request. Hopefully they support the orderby query parameter soon! https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/orderby-for-sharepoint-driveitems/idi-p/3684144#M1485